# Convert Buffer to PDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, blob, buffer

I am building a PDF using Puppeteer on the server and returning it as a Buffer to the client for download. I can't figure out why this conversion is not working for download. If I download it on the server side, everything works fine. Where am I going wrong?

```
onSuccess(data) {
      const blob = new Blob([data as Buffer], { type: 'application/pdf' })
      const link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      link.download = 'test.pdf'
      link.click()
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This always happens, I figure it out right after posting.

The answer is nuanced. I'm using React Query to get the data. The Buffer coming back from Node and Puppeteer looks like:

```js
{ type: Buffer, data: [...] }
```

The data to convert is on the data property, not the Buffer itself. So the correct code looks like this:

```
onSuccess(data) {
      const blob = new Blob([data.data as Buffer], { type: 'application/pdf' })
      const link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      link.download = 'test.pdf'
      link.click()
    },
```

This felt hacky (and made TS upset) so I kept searching and decided to convert the PDF to base64 before returning to client and that seems be working as well. On the server that looks like:

```js
 const pdf = await page.pdf()
 const base64 = pdf.toString('base64')
 return `data:application/pdf;base64,${base64}`
```